# Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'DATEVALUE()'

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I am new to the salesforce and trying to create the `formula` field, I have the following condition which I want to create.

```
(TODAY() - DATEVALUE( CreatedDate )) / (  CloseDate -  DATEVALUE(CloseDate) )
```

Error which I get:

```
Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'DATEVALUE()'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloseDate is already a date value, and does not need to be converted. Also, your formula is effectively an "#Error" value, because you can't divide by zero (X - X = 0). You'll need to adjust your algorithm.

```
1 - ((CloseDate - TODAY()) / (CloseDate - DATEVALUE( CreatedDate )))
```

We calculate days between close date and today, and divide by the number of days from the created date. We subtract from 1 to "invert" the value.

Comment: ((CloseDate - TODAY()) / (CloseDate - DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ))) works !!